# Subtract Time String in PHP

Tags: php, time

Say I have the following as a string:

$timeLeft = 00:02:30

I want to be able to subtract 1 second, turning it into 00:02:29.

I have tried

$timeLeft - 1;

But it does nothing.

How can I make it so I can subtract seconds from a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert it to a time, subtract 1 second and reformat, e.g.:

```
$timeLeft = '00:02:30';
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $timeLeft);
$time->sub(new DateInterval('PT1S'));
$timeLeft = $time->format('H:i:s');
```

Below is dirty code that performs the transformation "manually" by converting the time into seconds in case PHP 5.3+ is not available. It'll certainly misbehave it the number of seconds subtracted is greater than the total.

```
$timeLeft = '00:02:30';
list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $timeLeft);
$seconds += $hours*3600 + $minutes*60;
unset($hours, $minutes);
$seconds -= 1; //subtraction
$hours = floor($seconds/3600);
$seconds %= 3600;
$minutes = floor($seconds/60);
$seconds %= 60;
$timeLeft = sprintf("%'02u:%'02u:%'02u", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
```

Comment: I get this Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::createFromFormat() in /home/aleckaza/public_html/tests/penny_auction/functions.php on line 17

Comment: It requires PHP 5.3+. I bet your PHP version is too old. Note that the oldest supported release is 5.3.17.

Comment: How can I do this on an older PHP?

Comment: You may have to implement it yourself, I'm afraid. Running such an old version of PHP, however, is a bad idea for a number of reasons, including security.

Comment: @Alec I've posted an alternative "old PHP" solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using `strtotime` is a good practical solution, but you have to watch out for DST changes:

```
$tz = date_default_timezone_get(); // save old timezone
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); // switch to UTC

echo date('H:i:s', strtotime($timeleft) - 1); // perform calculation

date_default_timezone_set($tz); // restore old setting
```

Comment: Why do I need to watch out for the timezone? All I'm doing is subtracting a fixed time one second.

Comment: @Alec: Because of how `strtotime` works: it parses a full date/time and gives a timestamp, which corresponds to a specific moment in time. Using it to parse input such as yours (which is not a specific moment in time but rather a duration) is not what it's for. You can adapt it, but you have to account for how it's supposed to work.